# Как вызвать все элементы списка используя bot.send_message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, list, telebot

Здравствуйте у меня есть список и я его использую вместе с Telegram ботом и через функцию bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Название списка") я хочу вывести все элементы списка используя этот метод, но в этом случае выводится только нулевой(первый) элемент из списка, как я могу вызвать все элементы списка?
Вот пример[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
a = ["asdksadkdks", "sskdka", 2]


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handler(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id, a)
```

И если возможно мне нужен способ в котором мне необязательно знать сколько элементов в списке, так как в моем коде он реализован так, что постоянно добавляются и удаляются все элементы списка!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно отправлять каждый раз новое сообщение и брать элемент из списка, тогда циклом `for`:

```
for _ in a:
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id, _)
```

Если же нужно отправить все одним сообщением - тогда можно воспользоваться методом `join`:

```
chat_id = message.chat.id
bot.send_message(chat_id, '\n'.join(map(str, a)))
```

Comment: О спасибо как раз второе нужно было)

Answer (score 1):

Циклом `for`:

```py
for i in range(len(a)):
    bot.send_message(chat_id, a[i])
```